# Detect local maven repo corruption

Tags: bash, maven, maven-3

Every artifact downloaded from maven central comes with a `.sha1` file. Is there any way to force maven (or using a bash script) to re-validate the correctness of all its artifacts? I know that just deleting `.m2` is usually the recommended way when there's doubts about repo corruption, but if maven has checksums I imagine it is because there is a way to validate the artifacts

Comment: You can turn on the checksum verification in your `settings.xml` https://maven.apache.org/settings.html so a wrong checksum will fail your build ...But revalidation can not be done out of the box...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find anything using maven but this solution using bash worked for me

```
shopt -s globstar; for f in ~/.m2/**/*.jar; do if [[ -f $f.sha1 && $(sha1sum $f | cut -f1 -d " ") != $(cat $f.sha1 | cut -f1 -d " ") ]]; then echo Bad jar: $f; fi; done
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the accepted answer.

Some jars were marked as bad but while debugging I found that some of the `.sha1` files contained `\r` windows/mac line endings.

It also was single threaded, so I used `xargs` to run things in parallel (`-P8` below runs with 8 processes).

My version is:

```
function check_mvn_jar_files() {
    if [[ ! -f "$1.sha1" ]]; then
        echo "no sha1 file for $1"
        exit 1
    fi
    SUM=$(sha1sum "$1" | cut -f1 -d " ")
    FSUM=$(cat "$1.sha1" | cut -f1 -d " " | tr -d '\r')
    if [[ "${SUM}" != "${FSUM}" ]]; then
        echo "Bad jar: $1"
        echo "sha1=${SUM}"
        echo "file=${FSUM}"
    fi
}

export -f check_mvn_jar_files

find ~/.m2/repository/ -name "*.jar" -print0 |
    xargs -0 -P8 -n 1 bash -c 'check_mvn_jar_files "$@"' _
```

Timings on my system:

```
P1 - 20s
P4 - 7s
P8 - 5s
```